# What is Robyn singing in the music video for Royksopp's Monument?

Tags: lyrics, electronic-music

Robyn visibly sings something inaudible to the listener 52 seconds in to the music video for Royksopp's Monument. It seems to bridge the gap between the official lyrics.

What is she saying?

https://youtu.be/6c-RbGZBnBI?t=52s

Comment: I don't hear anything there beyond the vocal loop that begins the song. The first line is "make a space". The sounds before are processed looped voice "notes".

Comment: @Resber I'm referring to the music video specifically. Robyn visibly continues to sing between the gaps of "Make a space - for my body - dig a hole - push the sides apart" etc.

Answer (score 6):

According to YouTube user "[Rob RIN](https://www.youtube.com/user/r0br1n)" in his comment [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c-RbGZBnBI&lc=z12kg13a0xvhex1y404cjz1glxv3tbrwspw0k), the lyrics are as follows, with the inaudible in parentheses:

> Make a space, (please let us love)
>
> For my body, (so that I have enough)
>
> Dig a hole, (if you love)
>
> Push the sides apart,
>
> This is what, (it feels like)
>
> I'm controlling, (its fantastic)